# Missing Headlinetype dropdown menu entries after upgrade to typo3 9.5.15

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

Some days ago I upgraded my typo3 installation from 8.7.32 to typo3 9.5.15

This resulted in some error and I got fixed most of them, but this one problem is left:
When creating a new entry on a page, there is a field to type in your headline and a dropdown menu below, where you can chose the type of headline.
Before the update it stated things like *Seitenüberschrift - h1* and *Themenüberschrift - h2*.

Now after the update those options are missing. The dropdown menu still exists but it's entires are empty. Here is a screenshot of it:
[image: Missing dropdown options]

I'm not deep into typo3/typoscript so I don't even know where to start handling this problem.

// Addition: The problem apperas at multiple places. On the sceenshot below you can also see the field "Spalte". Changing the language to english doesn't help.

// Addition 2: It has something to do with the template "jweiland-Musterprojekt", which is the base of the website. Deactiviting this obiously destroys the whole site, but dropdown element are shown then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an answer myself after comparing each single file of the template of the new version to the template of the old version.

There was a file leftover called `ext_tables.php` which was removed in the newer version of the template.

This file included some old TSconfig files.

I wonder that missing translations were the only errors which were produced by this.